# Is the use of the Google Sign-in user ID a good idea to uniquely identify the entries stored in Firestore for this connected user?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

My app allows the user to store several pieces of information in Firestore (this information are typed in and using my app). To access these data, he must be connected: so I would want to use Google Sign-in (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating). Since I don't have any backend server and I don't have to access to any Google API server, I won't use OAuth 2.

After the user connects himself to its Google account within my app, I will be provided some of his information, including its account's ID.

Is it a good idea to store his Firestore's information under this ID? Thus, in Firestore, its ID would be stored as an entry, and in this entry's value, you will find his information.

**Is it legal to store his ID?** Do you have any other technical recommendation to fulfill this aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Asking for legal advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Below is based on technical capabilities and common practices. Please consult a council in your country for what is legally allowed.*

Within Firebase it is very common to store information about each user under their Firebase Authentication UID. This is a user identifier generated by Firebase, and ensures the identifiers are unique across all providers, and consistent in cases where the same user signs in with multiple providers. For example a user who signed in with Google first, may sign in with Facebook later, and Firebase Authentication allows you to link those two providers to a single account, which as a single UID.

If you only ever expect to use Google sign-in in your app, then the Google account ID can serve the same role.

Comment: Using Firebase Authentication UID means the user of my app has created its own Firebase's account. However, it has very little chance of happening. The users of my app are not computer scientists. They only have their Google account. If I don't want to use the Google Account ID but still the Firebase Authentication UID, is there any way to retrieve the latter from something?

Comment: To get the UID of the current Firebase Authentication user: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`. Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

Comment: But my user doesn't have any Firebase account. Just a Google one. Isn't it a problem?

Comment: It seems like you have a new problem, so please post it as a separate question.